# Strange segmentation fault in code

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Im really desperate that I don't know why this code gets a segmentation fault. This is supposed to put an element at the end of the linked. **n its never null but *n may be

```
int insertaFinal(Nodo **n, int dato){

    if (!*n){
        insertaInicio(n,dato);
        return 1;
    }

    Nodo* temp = *n;

    while (temp->sig)
        temp = temp->sig;

    temp -> sig = (Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    temp = temp->sig;
    temp->dato = dato;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: can you explain if (!*n){  ? did you mean this != null ?

Comment: what line does the segfault occur on?  what does gdb say?

Comment: Yep! should work the same way as NULL is false in C

Comment: The line is not told. IDK why if I remove  temp = temp->sig; it don't get the error

Comment: Your code doesn't deserve to work if you fail to check the return from `malloc()`.

Comment: Nice catch, already set a debug string for checking if pointer was allocated... anyway malloc only fails rarely

Comment: Can't you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3

Comment: What is `insertaInicio` ? What is `Nodo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "strange" about this. Here:

```
while (temp->sig)
    temp = temp->sig;
```

you appear to want to loop until `temp->sig` is `NULL`, but when you create new nodes, you never set this member to `NULL` in the first place, so clearly your loop is going to head out into unallocated memory. What you need to be doing is:

```
temp->sig = malloc(sizeof *temp->sig);
if ( !temp->sig ) {
    perror("Couldn't allocate memory for node");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
temp = temp->sig;
temp->dato = dato;
temp->sig = NULL;    //  <---- Add this line
```

If you don't set `sig` to `NULL` in `insertaInicio()` either, then you should, or even better, write a constructor function to avoid duplication and use it in both places.